# How to apply Swing animation in Bubble sorting algorithm?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, timing, pause

Am trying to visualize the actual swapping between arrays indexes but I am unable to make it slow to visualize. Want to make a pause in swapping so I can actually visualize it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
     private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
    private Timer timer;
    final JLabel lb = new JLabel();
    final JTextField txt = new JTextField();
    final JTextField[] val = new JTextField[5];
    final JTextField[] val1 = new JTextField[5];
    final JButton btn = new JButton();
    final JButton sort = new JButton();
    final JButton show = new JButton();
    int n;
    Container con;

    void Inint() {

        con = this.getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(null);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            val[i] = new JTextField();
        }
        lb.setText("Enter the size of aray ");
        lb.setBounds(100, 30, 150, 40);
        con.add(lb);

        txt.setBounds(100, 60, 50, 30);
        con.add(txt);
        btn.setText("OK");
        btn.setBounds(100, 100, 80, 30);
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        con.add(btn);

        sort.setText("Sort");
        sort.setBounds(100, 300, 80, 30);
        sort.addActionListener(this);

        show.setText("Show sorting");
        show.setBounds(200, 300, 80, 30);
        show.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getSource() == btn) {

            n = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
            int k = 80;
            int j = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                con.revalidate();
                val[i].setBounds(k, 160, 50, 25);

                con.add(val[i]);
                k = k + 50;
                con.add(sort);

            }
        }
        if (ae.getSource() == sort) {
            int a, b;
       
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {

                con.revalidate();

                for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {

                    int temp = 0;
                    a = Integer.parseInt(val[j].getText());
                    b = Integer.parseInt(val[j + 1].getText());

                    if (a > b) 
                    {

                        temp = a;
                        a = b;
                        b = temp;
                        String val1 = Integer.toString(b);
                        String val2 = Integer.toString(a);

                        val[j].setText(val2);  
                        val[j + 1].setText(val1);
```

Here is b/w about 2 line i want to make little pause kindly help me am new to java I am trying to visualize that how the boxes are being swapped!

```
                    }
                }
            }
            con.add(show);
        }
        if (ae.getSource() == show) {
            int k = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                val1[i] = new JTextField();
                String srt = val[i].getText();
                val1[i].setText(srt);

                val1[i].setBounds(k, 250, 50, 25);
                con.add(val1[i]);
                k = k + 50;
            }
        }

//throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

`Traffic` class

```
public class Traffic {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test tst = new test();
        tst.setVisible(true);
        tst.setBounds(200, 220, 400, 500);
        tst.Inint();
        tst.setDefaultCloseOperation(tst.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: val[j].setText(val2);  
 in b/w these lines i want to small pause
   val[j + 1].setText(val1);

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or ..

Comment: .. [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). **4) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.** 5) Don't make comments below a question when unless replying to someone. Better to [edit] the question. 6) Add appropriate tags for best results. I removed the [tag:add] tag and added Java and Swing instead.